# WHERE query not functioning properly

Tags: php, mysql

I have this query:

```
$queryfile = "UPDATE Glasovi
             SET Fotografija='$content',
             MD5Slike='$checksum'
             WHERE Email ='$email'";
```

It won't update the database.

When I write the email directly in the `WHERE` clause, it works:

```
$queryfile = "UPDATE Glasovi
              SET Fotografija='$content',
              MD5Slike='$checksum'
              WHERE Email ='user.user@mail.com'";
```

I tried to echo the `$email` variable and it has the right value.
Where is the error in the first query?

Comment: do `var_dump($queryfile)`, take a look at it, and if you need help with it, add it to your question :-)

Comment: I don't find any problems with the syntax of your queries. Double check all the variables, the contents of the database and the code you posted in the question.

Comment: I tryied query today and it works. It seems that something happened with server.

Answer (score 1):

your request is ok, so you should check your variables in php, use `var_dump($email)`

-- EDIT --

**Your request doesn't seem to be secure, you should use PDO statements to secure it from SQL injections**

Comment: "when you use '$email' you send the string $email". This is not true. Just tried in PHP 5.3.10. The documentation does not state this either.

Comment: ok i tested and edited my post, ty for your precision, you can now remove your vote down, it didn't worth it :)

Comment: My point is still valid. Your statements for string interpolation are just wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Your query looks correct. The only issue I can see is one of the other variables contains a single quote, which could possibly result in your error.

try using addslashes escape any single quotes in your variable

```
$queryfile = "UPDATE Glasovi 
SET Fotografija ='".addslashes($content)."', 
MD5Slike ='".addslashes($checksum)."' 
WHERE Email ='".addslashes($email)."'";
```

Doing so would also help prevent SQL injection by single quotes

Comment: +1 The security concerns in the query are obvious. I didn't thought of possible problems in the `$content` variable.

Answer (score -2):

You have not concatenated your variables with your string.

Change your code to this:

```
$queryfile="UPDATE Glasovi SET Fotografija=' . $content . ', MD5Slike=' . $checksum . ' WHERE Email =' . $email . '";
```

Comment: he does not haves to concatenate because he is using `"` and not `'` containers... 
you can put variables inside `"`

Comment: and you're strarting a string with `"` and finishing it with `'` in your example... but excepted these 2 things, it would work

Comment: i guess, it also could happen to me, i prefer use `'` than `"` and concatenate vars

Comment: Like this: $queryfile="UPDATE Glasovi SET Fotografija= $content , MD5Slike= $checksum WHERE Email = $email"

Comment: I personally would write the query like this
$queryfile = "UPDATE Glasovi SET Fotografija='" . $content . "', MD5Slike='" . $checksum . "', WHERE Email='" . $email . "';

But there might be better ways